# How to detect adjacent items in flot using a bootstrap tooltip

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, flot

I'm switching my flot graphs towards using bootstrap tooltips. I've encountered an *bug* where if two items are close together the tooltip doesn't follow.

[image: error in flot]

As you can see in the image above, I'm hovering the lower datapoint while the bootstrap tooltip still is stuck on the datapoint above.

I'm using the following code. I guess the problem is situated at `if(item)` which stays true while hovering down. I was thinking of working with a global variable but that seems like a messy solution. Any ideas?

```
placeholder.bind('plothover', function (event, pos, item) {

        if (item) {
            var x = item.datapoint[0],
                y = item.datapoint[1],
                label = item.series.label;

            box.css({
                top: item.pageY - 2,
                left: item.pageX + 1
            });

            if ($('.tooltip').length === 0) {
                box.tooltip({
                    placement: 'top',
                    title: label + ': ' + y
                }).tooltip('show');
            }
        } else {
            box.tooltip('destroy');
        }
    });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dietervdf/zb2vomoj/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The global variable to store for which item the tooltip is shown is the default solution in flot for this, something like this here:

```
prevItem = null;
placeholder.bind('plothover', function (event, pos, item) {

    if (item) {
        if (prevItem != item.dataIndex + item.seriesIndex / 100) {
            prevItem = item.dataIndex + item.seriesIndex / 100;

            // show / update tooltip
        }
    } else {
        prevItem = null;
        box.tooltip('destroy');
    }
});
```

I tried to get this working in your fiddle and it worked most of the time. But there are some issues with the bootstrap tooltip which sometimes not updates the text properly. Always destroying and recreating the tooltip solves this but brings back the flicker.